# Bind Variables and Inconsistent Results in SOSL

Tags: apex, sosl

I have some Apex code that does a SOSL query. If it uses bind variables, some users don't get results. If I build the query with string concatenation, then the results are consistent across users.

Here is a code snippet that demos this.

```
Id quoteRecordId = 'a1z6t0000008o0m';
String searchKeyword = 'QL*';

String query1 = 'FIND :searchKeyword IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING SBQQ__QuoteLine__c(Id, Name, SBQQ__Product__r.Name WHERE SBQQ__Quote__c = :quoteRecordId AND SBQQ__SegmentIndex__c = 1)';
String query2 = 'FIND :searchKeyword IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING SBQQ__QuoteLine__c(Id, Name, SBQQ__Product__r.Name WHERE SBQQ__Quote__c = \'' + quoteRecordId + '\' AND SBQQ__SegmentIndex__c = 1)';

List<List<sObject>> sobjectList1 = Search.query(query1); // no results
List<List<sObject>> sobjectList2 = Search.query(query2); // two results

System.assertEquals(sobjectList1[0].size(), sobjectList2[0].size());
```

If I run this code as another system admin, both queries result in two results. Any ideas?

I tried to replicate this in a dev org with the following code, but I'm getting the same results in both queries (one record returned).

```
Id accountId = '001U0000003Kb3CIAS';
String searchKeyword = 'Andy*';

String query1 = 'FIND :searchKeyword IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Id, FirstName, LastName, Account.Name WHERE AccountId = \'' + accountId + '\' AND Name = \'Dickenson plc\')';
String query2 = 'FIND :searchKeyword IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Id, FirstName, LastName, Account.Name WHERE AccountId = :accountId AND Name = \'Dickenson plc\')';

List<List<sObject>> sobjectList1 = Search.query(query1);
List<List<sObject>> sobjectList2 = Search.query(query2);

System.assertEquals(sobjectList1[0].size(), sobjectList2[0].size());
```

Comment: On reason I can think of is ,if you dont add `order by` keyword the result may or may not be same everytime, try adding a `order by` and check the result.

Comment: Adding an order by doesn't change the results

Comment: We are experiencing this same issue in our org right now, specifically surrounding the binding of record Ids to Lookup fields. Did you ever find a solution? Starting to feel like this is a bug.

Comment: I just switched to use string concatenation. I think it is a bug too, but since I couldn't replicate it in a dev org, I didn't want to bang my head against Salesforce support.

Comment: @MorganMarchese are you seeing this with custom or standard objects?

Comment: @DanielHoechst my org has direct access to a Salesforce Program Architect so I connected with him last week. He said this should work exactly the same as SOQL strings (where binds work fine) and that there were some changes to SOSL a few years ago to fix a performance issue that may have unintentionally impacted this functionality. He also recommended string concatenation for now, but we're exploring opening a known issue for it as well (so long as we can reproduce in UAT). In our case, we're searching for a custom object and the only problematic bind is the AccountId lookup, other binds work